# "zeros" matrix of UTF8String is hard to create

Tags: julia

when trying to initialize an array of UTF8Strings to "", I came across the following problem:

```
julia> zeros(UTF8String,1)
1-element Array{ASCIIString,1}:
 ""
```

Somehow the zero string is converted to ASCIIString.

```
julia> typeof(zeros(UTF8String,1))
Array{ASCIIString,1}
```

Should it not be the case that an invariant of the following should hold:

```
typeof(zeros(T,n))==Array{T,1}
```

I ended up using an uninitialized array.

Is this an issue to report or is it a logical result?

Comment: the versioninfo is Julia Version 0.3.0-prerelease+2733

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An empty UTF8String array may be created with:

```
julia> utfstr = UTF8String[]
```

(the `zeros(UTF8String,1)` syntax has been removed on the current trunk)

Comment: i was going for an array of empty ("") strings.

Comment: I think this is a DataFrames method: [`Base.zeros{T<:String}(::Type{T},args...) = fill("",args...)`](https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataFrames.jl/blob/master/src/dataframe/dataframe.jl#L868)

Comment: thanks. you are right Matt. maybe DataFrames should have:
fill(convert(T,""),args...)

Comment: The historical use of `zero`/`zeros` in DataFrames codebase was pretty problematic and has been largely removed.